# How to fix StatementInvalid error with Stripe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I'm working on payment system with Stripe.
I have to search customer after receiving stripe webhook. But this error below occurs.

---

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (SQLite3::SQLException: near "'cus_xxxxx'": syntax error: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (stripe_customer_id 'cus_xxxxx') ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?):

---

Customer which has `cus_xxxxx` exists. But I have to remove single quotation from this...

```
@user = User.where('stripe_customer_id ?', "#{source['customer'].gsub("'", "")}").first
```

I have tried like this. But that wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you aren’t using an operator in the query. Ex:`stripe_customer_id = ?` or `stripe_customer_id IN (?)`. But there’s a better way to write this.

```
@user = User.find_by({
  stripe_customer_id: source['customer'].delete("'")
})
```

`find_by` takes similar arguments to `where`, but returns the first record. Also, the Hash syntax automatically chooses between `=`, `IN`, or `IS NULL` depending on the value provided.

Also, you can use the `delete` method to remove all occurrences of a string within a string. Benchmarks show that it’s faster than gsub. It is odd to me that you need to modify the string like this though. I feel like whatever is submitting `source` is doing it wrong if there’s extra quotes.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much, I achieve that.